# Is there a WhatsApp library like Sulla, but for Python?

Tags: library, python, chat, whatsapp

As the title has described. I am looking for a "standard" way (i.e. not handling the http requests myself but with classes and methods to do so) to perform WhatsApp actions automatically with Python, e.g. send messages, receive messages etc.

I have really liked the Sulla framework (https://github.com/danielcardeenas/sulla) which is available for JavaScript, but I am not able to get very far since I haven't learned JavaScript yet and it feels a little unnecessary to learn an entirely new language just for a framework.

Do you have any advice?

PS: I have already searched for Python WhatsApp libraries, but they don't seem to offer as much functionality as Sulla.